# Ajax refresh/update sum from a GridView Column to a TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I have a GridView A that have many columns, one of those contains price for each row. so the cue is how or in which way, can I update/refresh the total price that will be showed in a Label or TextBox (not in GridView Footer)?

My working platform is C# 3.0 / ASP.Net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a "total" variable.  Use jquery to iterate through each row of your table/gridview and add the particular column value to to the total. (The method would need to know to get the numeric value out of the Td or the text input.

On the onchange event of the textbox, call the method again.

Comment: where can i find an example of using JQuery?, i just know a single jscript lib calls Extjs. Thanks!

Comment: do a search for jquery on this site would be a good start.  Google jquery reference and jquery tutorial and I am sure you will get what you need.